# Shifting the border-left to border-right CSS

Tags: css

Hi I have  a CSS code with the following style property.

```css
.spotlight{
    border-left: 21px solid #ffb80d;
}
```

I need to move the spotlight to right for RTL changes.I need to add a change like

```css
.locale-right-to-left .spotlight {
     border-right: 21px solid #ffb80d;
}
```

But if I make this change there will be 2 spotlights on both sides of the text. Is there a way where I can ignore the border-left property ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.locale-right-to-left .spotlight {
    border-right: 21px solid #ffb80d;
    border-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: .locale-right-to-left .spotlight
{
   border-right: 21px solid #ffb80d;
   border-left: 0;
}  This change works fine for me Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Define border-left 0

```css
.locale-right-to-left .spotlight
{
   border-right: 21px solid #ffb80d;
   border-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: .locale-right-to-left .spotlight
{
   border-right: 21px solid #ffb80d;
   border-left: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you use :

```css
element {
    direction:rtl;
}
```

then draw your border from a pseudo-element:

```css
element {
    direction:rtl;
}
element .spotlight{
    position:relative;
}
element .spotlight:before {
    position:absolute;
    left:auto;  /* no need*/
    right:auto; /* no need*/
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-left: 21px solid #ffb80d;/* or border-right */
}
```

The position of :before will relay on direction

Comment: test here http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/sHCxK (should I not use codepen.io , if so i'm curious) :)